# I need the frequency for the 2019 Ram 1500 Keyless Entry

Tags: keyless-entry

I'm sorry if this is the wrong forum for this, but this is the closest I could find.

I lost my keys. I've turned my home upside down and I can't find them. And I'm somewhat obsessive.

So I had an idea. Perhaps it's dumb, but it's the best I could come up with.

I went to Amazon and bought a $40 SDR kit. My car has keyless entry, so the hope was that I could walk around my house with my laptop and SDR kit, pick up on the keyless entry signal, and narrow down my search.

The kit came with a couple of antennas, a base, and a USB stick I could use to connect my antenna and my computer. I fired up GQRX. It was pretty straightforward to figure out. Tuned it to 315 Mhz, pulled out the keys to my Mustang, and voila, worked like a charm. Unfortunately, it did not work for my Ram keys. So I searched the Googles for a while, and found that for older model Rams, the key fobs were set to 433 Mhz. So I set it to 433 Mhz, and though it was a lot more difficult to pick out this signal, I do believe it was there, and that I could hear it when the button was pressed. But I could not see the keyless signal whatsoever. No matter how close I brought the keys to the antenna. So, I'm hoping, that perhaps I have the wrong frequency for the keyless entry, and that I could tune to the right frequency and have it work.

However, if the signal is just to weak to pick up with my SDR system, I guess I'm SOL.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! 315 Mhz should be the right frequency. I was thinking though, might it not be transmitting unless a button is pressed or it is interrogated. I wouldn't have a clue what the interrogation frequency would be though, though it might be 315 Mhz as well (send/receive). I don't know this for sure, though. Just thinking outloud.

Comment: Ahh, I did not realize that there was such a thing as an interrogation frequency. I simply thought that it transmitted non-stop. That makes sense from a power saving perspective.

Comment: Will you pick up a short pulse duration? perhaps the device is only sending a small timeframe signal and the sweep frequency of your searching device misses it.

Comment: I think rolling code encryption was used in last 20 years. Talk to dealer.